# How to set User ID to Storage path in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an Restful API using Laravel 5 and MongoDB.
I'm saving avatar image for users.
It's working fine but I'm trying to create a Folder for every User. For example: `"app/players/images/USERID"`

I've tried to do something like this in different ways but I always get Driver [] is not supported.

```
\Storage::disk('players'.$user->id)->put($image_name, \File::get($image));
```

**UploadImage:**

```
    public function uploadImage(Request $request)
    {

    $token = $request->header('Authorization');
        $jwtAuth = new \JwtAuth();
    $user = $jwtAuth->checkToken($token, true);

        $image = $request->file('file0');

        $validate = \Validator::make($request->all(), [

            'file0' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'

        ]);

        if ( !$image || $validate->fails() ) 
        {

            $data = array(
                'code' => 400,
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Image uploading error-'
            );

        }
        else
        {

            $image_name = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
            \Storage::disk('players')->put($image_name, \File::get($image));

            $user_update = User::where('_id', $user->id)->update(['imagen' => $image_name]);

            $data = array(
                'code' => 200,
                'status' => 'success',
                'user' => $user->id,
                'imagen' => $image_name
            );
        }


    return response()->json($data, $data['code']);
    }
```

**filesystems.php:**

```
        'players' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/players/images/'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

I expect the user avatar image saves on User ID folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk call, tells `Laravel` which filesystem to use, let's assume you have an user with Id one, with your code it will access the filesystem playeers1.

What usually is done is to put these files in folder structures for the different users, so instead you could do. This will put your image file, in the folder 1.

```
\Storage::disk('players')->put($user->id . '/' . $image_name, \File::get($image));
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to specify the folder on disk('players') instead of put().

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, check if the lines can change what you want to achieve.

```
\Storage::disk('players')->put("{$user->id}/{$image_name}", \File::get($image));
```

I relied on the laravel guide: [File Storage - File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads)

I hope it helps you. A cordial greeting.